# Connectivity in a dual boot

Tags: wireless-card

I have this problem. On a Asus notebook (not uefi) I upgraded Windows 7 **Home Premium** to 10. After this, I installed another copy of Windows, precisely Windows 7 **Pro** on a logical partition.

I've got soon the dual boot, but when I access Windows 7, I cannot activate the Wi-Fi anymore with the dedicated button on the keyboard.

I notice however that the corresponding led is turned on at the start, but the connection doesn't work, it seems as there isn't a network card, but obviously this is untrue, in fact in Windows 10 it works properly.

With the diagnostic for the network, I get something as, 'Unable to detect a correctly installed network card.

I don't understand the reason, I don't think I have to install manually the driver, and I cannot figure out if it may depend on the different version of Windows, that's Pro instead of Home.

Comment: I don't think the version of Windows should matter. You'll likely just need to manually download drivers from the manufacturer's website for each component that doesn't work.

Comment: @multithr3at3d I think that too.. but in the meantime I've installed 2 drivers - LAN and WLAN - from the principal partition Win10. Now, the first was okay, but the second warned me at the end of the process, that the corresponding hardware could be removed, in other words absent, not retrievable, and soon after this the installation terminated successfully. Now I get access to the web using tethering, and this is fine for me. But I'd really like to understand the reason for the wirless failure and the persistent impossibility to activate it..